# Refactoring similar methods using generics parameter in c# and linq

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have two methods they are exactly the same except the first parameter.I don't want to repeat the duplicate code. I was wondering how can we refactor the following code using generic parameters.

First method

```
 private Dictionary<List<string>, List<string>> GetFinancialLtmDataSet(List<sp_get_company_balance_sheet_amount_ltm_Result> itemResult, int neededyear)
    {
        var requestedData =
            itemResult.OrderByDescending(x => x.date.Year).Take(neededyear).Select(x => new { date = x.date.Date });

        var addFields = new List<string>();
        var dataSet = new Dictionary<List<string>, List<string>>();
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (var itemy in requestedData)
        {
            var skipvalue = itemResult.Skip(counter);
            var columns = skipvalue.OrderBy(x => itemy.date).ToList();
            var cc = columns.First();
            counter++;
            var properties =
                cc.GetType()
                    .GetProperties()
                    .Select(x => new { Name = x.Name, Value = x.SetMethod, a = x.GetValue(cc, null) })
                    .ToList();

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                addFields.Add(property.Name);
                if (property.a != null)
                {
                    dataSet.Add(new List<string> { property.Name }, new List<string> { property.a.ToString() });
                }
            }
        }
        return dataSet;
    }
```

Second method

```
private Dictionary<List<string>, List<string>> GetFinancialQuartelyDataSet(List<sp_get_company_balance_sheet_amount_quaterly_Result> itemResult, int neededyear)
    {
        var requestedData =
            itemResult.OrderByDescending(x => x.date.Year).Take(neededyear).Select(x => new { date = x.date.Date });

        var addFields = new List<string>();
        var dataSet = new Dictionary<List<string>, List<string>>();
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (var itemy in requestedData)
        {
            var skipvalue = itemResult.Skip(counter);
            var columns = skipvalue.OrderBy(x => itemy.date).ToList();
            var cc = columns.First();
            counter++;
            var properties =
                cc.GetType()
                    .GetProperties()
                    .Select(x => new { Name = x.Name, Value = x.SetMethod, a = x.GetValue(cc, null) })
                    .ToList();

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                addFields.Add(property.Name);
                if (property.a != null)
                {
                    dataSet.Add(new List<string> { property.Name }, new List<string> { property.a.ToString() });
                }
            }
        }
        return dataSet;
    }
```

I have created a following method to make it generic but not been able to get the final implementation any suggestion appreciated.

```
private List<T> GetFinancialReport<T>(List<T> data, int neededyear)
  {

       //what should I return from here 
        return data;
  }

and would like to use the above method  like this


 var balancesheetResult=balancesheet.ToList();
 var testData = GetFinancialReport<BalanceSheet_sp>(balancesheetResult, 5);

var cashflowresult=cashflow.ToList();
var testData1 = GetFinancialReport<CahsFlow_sp>(cashflowresult, 10);
```

Comment: The return type should then be `Dictionary<List<string>, List<string>>`, am I right? Also you could use an interface here instead of a generic parameter if the needed properties are common.

Comment: Do they (`CahsFlow_sp` and `BalanceShit_sp`) have something in common? Some base class/interface? No? Then how would method know what to select and what to populate?

Comment: Yes the return type should be Dictionary<List<string>, List<string>>

Comment: @Sinatr : Currently they don't have any common interface  or base class. Cashflow_sp  and balancesheet_sp  are  the stored procedure. The fields are common on both Cashflow_sp  and balancesheet_sp but there is no model defined at the moment. I am directly calling the stored procedure on my method.

Comment: @ Sasha Truf I am using Entity Framework to invoke my  SP.

Comment: @user3922960 So, it means you have auto-generated classes (sp_get_company_balance_sheet_amount_quaterly_Result, .....) which you can extend adding сommon interface (IBalance), because they are partial. More information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456844(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

From what is shown above the objects (at least the properties involved) match. So you could code against an interface here:

```
private Dictionary<List<string>, List<string>> GetFinancialReport(List<IBalance>, int neededyear) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for the pointers Could you please give me more detail about what should be inside IBalance Interface?

Comment: @user3922960 I think it should look like: `public interface IBalance { DateTime date {get; set;} }`